# Use the parent repository to save everything in APIRest

Tags: java, spring-boot, api, hibernate, jpa

So, till now I've been saving all my objects using the parent repository, for example, when I wanted to make a PUT request on a child object I did something like this:

parentId --> the id of the parent element

childId --> A reference id for the child element

child --> JSON Body send to update the child I had before

```
public void updateChildFromParent(Long parentId, int childId, Child child) {
List<Child> listChild = parentRepository.findById(parentId).get().getChild();
            if (!listChild.isEmpty()) {
                int sizeList = listChild.size();
                if ((childId- 1) < tamLista) {
                    Child childDB = listChild.get(childId - 1);
                    Long idReal = childDB.getId();
                    int idRefReal = childDB.getIdRef();
                    child.setId(idReal);
                    child.setIdRef(idRefReal);
                    childRepository.save(defGroup);
}}
```

As you can see what I'm doing is modifying the parent element and then saving it again. So my question is if this can be done like this or I should use another way of doing it, in order to save, modify or delete.

I'm new in SpringBoot API so I'm a little bit lost.

Thanks!

Comment: Unless `childId` is the same as the index in the collection (for which the order is not garantueed) this code is flawed... Just obtain the child directly and update, don't go through the parent.

Comment: @M.Deinum I totally forgot to explain that, yeah the reference id I use is just for the user to access a child without having to put the real id. When I save the child entity it overwrites the one that had that id, but my question is if in order to change child object of a parent is ok to save again the whole parent. And if it is not ok, how could I save it or edit it. Thank you very much ! :)

Comment: You can do it like this, but I would say this code is dangerous as there is no garantueed order. You are probably better of passing hte actual id and do a direct update (which is simpler and faster).

Comment: If you really want to do it this way I would create a field in `Child` `Integer index` or something similar which you check for with your id, but as previous comment stated would not get by list index directly

Comment: @M.Deinum The other way to achieve this would be using a repository for each entity and saving using their methods "save" or how? when I tried doing this it gave me errors related with the cascade I think :S